# jQuery $.each return "undefined" from numeric array

Tags: jquery

For example:

```
var d = [];

d[3] = 'qwe';
d[10] = '213';

console.log(d);
for(i in d){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(d[i]);
}

$.each(d, function(i, v){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(v);

});
```

First output: `[undefined, undefined, undefined, "qwe", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "213"]`

`for` loop returns only two right values, but `$.each` loop returns 10 elements with 8 "undefined". I understand why it happens, but I want use exactly jQuery `$.each` for my script.

Thanx.

Comment: You say *"first output"* has the undefineds, but the first code you show is the `for` loop which *won't* have those undefineds. I assume you mean you're seeing those in the `$.each` loop.

Answer (score 4):

The output you've shown doesn't match either of the loops you've shown, but the gist seems to be that you don't want to see the `undefined` array entries.

> I understand why it happens, but I want use exactly jQuery $.each for my script.

If you really want to do that, it's easy enough:

```
$.each(d, function(i, v){
    if (d.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(v);
    }
});
```

That will weed out the array indexes that don't exist in the array. You *could* use `typeof v[i] !== 'undefined'` but that will give you the incorrect result if you've actually set an array element to `undefined` (so it *exists*, but its value is `undefined`).

jQuery is iterating over the array in the normal way, starting with index `0` and going through to index `length - 1`. The `for..in` loop loops over the properties in the object, and so doesn't loop for non-existant array entries (but *will*, the way you've written it, pick up anything from `Array.prototype` that's enumerable; [more here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)).

Ways to loop things:

1. `$.each`; see above.
2. Specifically for arrays and array-like things, the staid but useful `for (index = 0; index < v.length; ++index)`. In this case, because the array is sparse, you'll want `v.hasOwnProperty(i)` or `typeof v[i] !== 'undefined'` (if you don't care about the case I listed above) to make sure you're seeing an entry that exists.
3. For objects in general (including arrays, but you have to be careful): `for..in`:

   ```
   for (propName in v) {
       // Check whether `v` has the property itself, or inherited it
       if (v.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
           // `v` has the property itself

           // If looping an array or array-like thing and you want to see
           // only the *elements* (properties with numeric indexes) and
           // skip any non-element properties:
           if (String(parseInt(propName, 10)) === propName) {
               // It's an array element
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @Raynos: Did I have a typo in that first version? Never mind, I changed it anyway, but thanks.

Comment: This would certainly get +1 from me if I didn't hit the vote cap - see you in 15 hours :)

Comment: Isn't it d.hasOwnProperty(i) in your first snippet (d instead of v) ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, if you use `$.each` on an array, it uses a normal `for` loop to iterate over it

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

and a lot of indices in your array are `undefined`.

`for...in` instead only loops over the properties of the object which are present.  But you should never loop over an array with `for...in`.

Maybe using an object instead of an array is better in your case.

```
var d = {}; // <-- object

d[3] = 'qwe';
d[10] = '213';
```

Comment: +1 for *you should never loop over an array with `for...in`*.

Comment: @FelixKling is it that bad to use an array as a hash when all your keys are numerical?

Comment: Yes, but I can't use `length` method for object. I must write additional function to count objects elements.

Comment: @Andrey d.length returns 11 in that example. That's probably not what you wanted anyway.

Comment: @Raynos: I would say one should use the right data structure for the right situation. An array should be used if you have a collection of elements that just have to be indexed. But as soon as I don't want/have continuous keys, I would use an object.

Comment: @FelixKing true. I agree there that an object is better for non continious keys.

Comment: @Andrey: As @Raynos says, you would have to count the values in any way. This is another reason why not use an array in this case, even with numerical keys. The behaviour is different from what one might expect.

Comment: @FelixKling, sorry, my bad, i don't check that =( Use object is best and only one solution. Thanx.

Comment: @Felix: "*But you should never loop over an array with for...in."* Oh, it's a perfectly good way to loop over sparse arrays. You just have to understand what you're doing, and do the proper checks (`hasOwnProperty` to make sure that the property isn't inherited, and optionally `String(parseInt(propName, 10)) === propName` to check whether the property defines an array *element* (as the spec puts it) or just some other property you've assigned to the array.

Answer (score 1):

`$.each()` is iterating over the `Array` as an `Array` (probably via a `for`). When you place a member in an array, everything that is less than upper bound that is not defined becomes `undefined`.

When you use `for ( in )`, you are iterating over the enumerable properties of an object. In this case, it is only the properties you set.

If you simply want to subscript `Array` members, use a `for` loop.

If you want properties (unordered) from an `Object`, use `for ( in )`.

Answer (score 0):

you should trying to except undefined strings with something like that

```
if (v != "undefined")
{
   console.log(v)
}
```

Comment: ... it's `v !== undefined` or `typeof v !== "undefined"`

Comment: Yes, of course, but very uncomfortable write this in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (; i < length;) {
    if (callback.apply(object[i++], args) === false) {
        break;
    }
}
```

From the jQuery source. It iterates over every keyed element if it's not an object. So it handles arrays seperately.

This means it catches all elements between 0 and `array.length`. If you don't want this behaviour then don't use `jQuery.each`.

Of course if your using ES5 you can just call `.forEach` on your array ~

```
d.forEach(function(val, key) {
   // stuff
});
```

This will only handle two entries.